# Java 7 copy files routine fails completely

Tags: java, html, file, copy, java-7

I have copied from many places what is held to be the correct script to copy a file from A to B using Java 7.  I have downloaded Java 7 and absolutely nothing happens when I run the page.  I am doing (or maybe NOT doing) something very basic that is wrong.  Can you tell me what I need?  I am using this script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)" />
<meta name="created" content="Sun, 17 Feb 2013 15:50:39 GMT" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />

  </head>
  <body>
<Script>
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;


public class Copier {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     //Copy file /foo/x.txt to /bar directory
     String source = "C:/Users//Mike/test.txt";
     String target = "C:/Users/Mike/test1.txt";
     Copier.copyFile(source, target);
 }

    public static void copyFile(String source, String target) {
     try {
         Files.copy(new File(source).toPath(), new File(target).toPath(),
             StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
 }

 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you really embed *java* (not javascript) code inside an html document like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```javascript
<script>
(java code)
</script>
```

You can't do that. You have to compile the code with `javac` and then run it with `java` instead.

Here is an example:

```
cd C:/path/to/the/file/
javac TheFileName.java
java TheFileName
```

**Java is *NOT* Javascript!**

Comment: OK - thanks from a complete noobie.  Back to the drawing board!